# How to open another app from my app via Mobilepush?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilesdk

I would like to open Instagram app or Facebook app if my customers click on any of the links from my push notifications. Is there any way of doing this from the SDK for Android and iOS?

I've been looking at OpenDirect and Deep Links but it is not clear for me if this is possible.

If it is, could anyone say to me how or share documentation?

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What can/cannot be opened on either platform has nothing to do with the SDKs. Messages sent to the devices can have URLs (OpenDirect) and/or contain additional data within their payloads (Custom Keys, etc).  What your application does with that data is entirely up to you as you must provide a URL handler and/or override notification handling to parse and use Custom Keys (ref. [Android and iOS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/mobile-push-sdk.htm))

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for your quick answer. How can I know if OpenDirect is working properly and it is not an issue with the SDK?

Comment: Are you experiencing an issue?  The URL is passed in the notification.  From there it is 100% up to your application to parse and handle it.  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug

Comment: Hi Bill, What I mean is. I can handle notifications from the SDK, what is this URL? https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html

So I would like when I click on the URL from the push notification to open my webpage instead of my app. isn't that possible?

Comment: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/sdk-implementation/url-handling.html